# hide some pages from php pagination system with sql

Tags: php, mysqli, pagination, hide

As the title says, I want to hide some pages from my pagination system. Because the table that it selects from is huge so it creates thousands of numbers.

So i want it to be something like
First Page 1 2 3 4 ... Last Page

And if i click on page for it should show this
First Page 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ... Last page

And if i click on page 8 it should show this
First page ... 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ... Last Page

So here is my php pagination script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PHP Pagination</title>
  </head>
<body>
    <table align="center" border="2" cellpadding="3">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>quality</th>
            <th>RequiredLevel</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
            $con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'ascent', 'world');

            $per_page=500;

            if (isset($_GET["page"])) {
                $page = $_GET["page"];
            }else{
                $page=1;
            }

            $start_from = ($page-1) * $per_page;

            $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT name, Quality, RequiredLevel  FROM item_template LIMIT $start_from, $per_page");

            $stmt->execute();

            $stmt->bind_result($name, $quality, $reqlvl);

            $stmt->store_result();

            while($stmt->fetch()) {

                if($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
                    echo "<tr align='center'>";
                    echo "<td>$name</td>";
                    echo "<td>$quality</td>";
                    echo "<td>$reqlvl</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            }
        ?>
    </table>
    <div>
        <?php
            $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM item_template");

            $stmt->execute();


            $stmt->store_result();

            if($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
                $total_records = $stmt->num_rows;
                $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $per_page);

                echo "<center><a href='index.php?page=1'>First Page</a>";

                for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {
                    if($page < 4)
                    echo "<a href='index.php?page=$i'>$i</a> ";
                }

                echo "<a href='index.php?page=$total_pages'>Last Page</a></center> ";       
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You shouldn't query the whole table if you won't render it, use offset/limit to query only a subset of the records.

Comment: You can take idea from codeigniter pagination library https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/fa91f30c144c041ad19925e55fe06c4065337896/system/libraries/Pagination.php

Comment: I am using a limit in the other query. This piece of code is just my pagination system. So it will only make links for my pages. Maybe i should just post the whole script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The solution** for your pagination problem is this:

- Get the current page number using the superglobal `$_GET`,

  ```
  // current page
  $current_page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
  ```
- Find the superset range of pages, like 1-10, or 1-20 etc. For example, if `$total_pages = 30` then this superset range would be 1-30. The code for this step is this:

  ```
  // superset range of pages
  $superset_range = range(1, $total_pages);
  ```
- Find the subset range of pages to display, like 1-7, or 3-9 etc. For example, if `$total_pages = 30` then this subset range would be 1-7, or 3-9, or 6-12 etc., it can be any consecutive seven pages between 1 and 30. Also, adjust this range whenever necessary. The code for this step is this:

  ```
  // subset range of pages to display
  $subset_range = range($current_page - 3, $current_page + 3);

  // adjust the range(if required)
  foreach($subset_range as $p){
      if($p < 1){
          array_shift($subset_range);
          if(in_array($subset_range[count($subset_range) - 1] + 1, $superset_range)){
              $subset_range[] = $subset_range[count($subset_range) - 1] + 1;
          }
      }elseif($p > $total_pages){
          array_pop($subset_range);
          if(in_array($subset_range[0] - 1, $superset_range)){
              array_unshift($subset_range, $subset_range[0] - 1);
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Finally, display the pagination links and dots accordingly. The code for this step is this:

  ```
  // display intermediate pagination links
  if($subset_range[0] > $superset_range[0]){
      echo " ...&nbsp;";
  }
  foreach($subset_range as $p){
      echo "<a href='index.php?page=$p'>$p</a>";

  }
  if($subset_range[count($subset_range) - 1] < $superset_range[count($superset_range) - 1]){
      echo "&nbsp;... ";
  }
  ```

So, here's **the complete code**:

```
// your code

$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM item_template");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

if($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    $total_records = $stmt->num_rows;
    $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $per_page);

    if($total_records > $per_page){
        echo "<center><a href='index.php?page=1'>First Page</a> ";

        // current page
        $current_page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;

        // Superset range of pages
        $superset_range = range(1, $total_pages);

        // subset range of pages to display
        $subset_range = range($current_page - 3, $current_page + 3);

        // adjust the range(if required)
        foreach($subset_range as $p){
            if($p < 1){
                array_shift($subset_range);
                if(in_array($subset_range[count($subset_range) - 1] + 1, $superset_range)){
                    $subset_range[] = $subset_range[count($subset_range) - 1] + 1;
                }
            }elseif($p > $total_pages){
                array_pop($subset_range);
                if(in_array($subset_range[0] - 1, $superset_range)){
                    array_unshift($subset_range, $subset_range[0] - 1);
                }
            }
        }

        // display intermediate pagination links
        if($subset_range[0] > $superset_range[0]){
            echo " ...&nbsp;";
        }
        foreach($subset_range as $p){
            echo "<a href='index.php?page=$p'>$p</a>";

        }
        if($subset_range[count($subset_range) - 1] < $superset_range[count($superset_range) - 1]){
            echo "&nbsp;... ";
        }

        echo " <a href='index.php?page=$total_pages'>Last Page</a></center> ";  
    }    
}
```